# Spring batch/Postgres 9.3 : HibernateCursorItemReader returns zipped data in incorrect format

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch, postgresql-9.3

We have just migrated our application from a PostgreSQL 8.4 + java 5 to a PostgreSQL 9.3 and java 6.
I have an item reader with a simple HibernateCursorItemReader returning a mix of data including a zipped field. 
With the upgrade the data returned by the reader now have an "unzipped data:error->Not in GZIP format" but it is working correctly if I test it on the old system (with the old driver).
I have tried both

The configuration is below :

```
<beans:bean id="extractionItemReader" scope="step"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader">
<beans:property name="queryString">
  <beans:value>
     <![CDATA[
      select bilan, data, bank from 
        BilanCustomer bilan,
        BilanCustomerData data, 
        CustomerBank bank
      where 
        bilan.customer.key='CNCE' and
        bilan.status=1 and
        bilan.documentType.code='EBCDIC' and
        bilan.disabled=false and
        bilan.bilanCustomerData.identifiant=data.identifiant and
        bilan.customerBank.identifiant=bank.identifiant
      ]]>
  </beans:value>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Added (28/01/2015) :

Datasource is :

```
 <local-tx-datasource>
     <jndi-name>bilanDatasource</jndi-name> 
     <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5432/PBILD</connection-url>
     <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
     <user-name>*****</user-name>
     <password>****</password>
 </local-tx-datasource>
```

The field getting the zipped data is 'bicd_data'in the table BilanCustomerData :

```
bicd_id                 bigint         NOT NULL,
bicd_version            timestamp      NOT NULL,
bicd_date               timestamp      NOT NULL,
bicd_name               varchar(50),
**bicd_data               bytea**,
bicd_disabled           boolean,
bic_for_c               varchar(3),
...
```

Libs are :

```
Hibernate : 3.3.1.GA
Spring version : 2.5.6
Spring batch : 2.0.1.RELEASE
```

Comment: My hunch is that this is a driver/datasource issue.  Can you provide the details about those?

Comment: Micheal, I added the datasource. I have tried both the jdbc3 and jdbc4 drivers for the version of the database.

Comment: Just to confirm something...since I'm assuming there was a data migration involved here (or upgrade of some kind), if you run the code against the new db with the old driver, does it work?

Comment: The data was migrated from the old to the new DB and the old driver does not support the new one. Accessing the object through a full-blown JEE   DAO seems to return a correctly formed object.

Comment: Can you provide the table definition?  Also, what versions of Hibernate, Spring, and Spring Batch are in use?